# How to instantiate or mock a Window programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

For some of my unit tests I have to call methods that require a Window as parameter. Unfortunately I can't pass null, since the method uses the window as a reference to update the status bar where I show what is actually loaded in the real application.

So I tried to call the constructor in the unit test:

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
```

But this results in the following error on the InitializeComponent method of the MainWindow constructor:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message='Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '9' and line position '42'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=9
  LinePosition=42
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       Message=Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() returns null. Set the Application.ResourceAssembly property or use the pack://application:,,,/assemblyname;component/ syntax to specify the assembly to load the resource from.
       Source=PresentationFramework
       StackTrace:
            at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetResourceManagerWrapper(Uri uri, String& partName, Boolean& isContentFile)
            at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetPartCore(Uri uri)
            at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPartHelper(Uri partUri)
            at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPart(Uri partUri)
            at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
            at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
            at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
            at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
            at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
            at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy)
            at System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
            at System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       InnerException:
```

So my question is, how can I instantiate or mock a window in unit testing?

Comment: Seems like this should be a red flag that you need to look at you separation of concerns.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if(Application.ResourceAssembly == null)
    Application.ResourceAssembly = typeof(MainWindow).Assembly;
var window = new MainWindow();
```

Comment: Can you provide 1 or two lines more? How can I now use a object of MainWindow as a parameter when calling another method?

Comment: Also, your unit tests have to be running in an STA thread to do this.  Also also, as for your last sentence... wat?  Sounds like a new question.  I don't know what you're asking, but it sounds outside the scope of this one.

Comment: @Roflcoptr `method(window)`, unless you're asking something different; MainWindow is a subclass of `Window`, which you've said is a parameter of your method...

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is that you shouldn't. Unit Testing is **not done on UI**.

Unit Tests should be run on your logical code, and that's where patterns like MVC and MVVM come to help. The UI should be tested using tools like CodedUI.

if your logic has a dependency on UI, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: CodedUI is crazy expensive. And sometimes you want to start the application in the same process (for easy coverage logging and debugging for instance).