# How to mock Application.Current for unit-testing?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mocking, mstest

I have this:

```
<Image.Effect>
    <fx:GrayscaleEffect DesaturationFactor="0"/>
</Image.Effect>
```

and this:

```
public class GrayscaleEffect : ShaderEffect{
    private static PixelShader _pixelShader = new PixelShader()
        {
            UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Effects/GrayscaleEffect.ps")
        };
    /* ... rest of the class ... */
}
```

When I unit-test it (`MSTest`), it obviously raises `IOException` (since `Application.Current` is null, so `pack://application:,,,/...` points to nowhere) with this error:

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() returns null. Set the Application.ResourceAssembly property or use the pack://application:,,,/assemblyname;component/ syntax to specify the assembly to load the resource from.`

How do I mock/inject whatever needed to resolve it ?

Comment: I think it would be easier to inject the Uri into the GrayscaleEffect. Would that work for you?

Comment: @DanielSklenitzka: yes. How ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it, thanks to [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5503866/587467):

```
if(Application.ResourceAssembly == null)
    Application.ResourceAssembly = typeof(MainWindow).Assembly;

var window = new MainWindow();
```

Answer (score 4):

Tal's answer didnt work for me, I am just calling below before running my test and Application.Current is populated:

```
var app = new Application();
```