# Unit test throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, nunit

I've been trying to run a test on a method that loads data from an xml file and returns it as a list, however, I keep getting a NullReferenceException when it runs. I've checked and my filepath is fine.

```
[TestCase(1)]
public void firstTest(int num)
{
    var studentList = StudentListGenerator.CreateStudentList(@"../../TestReport/TestData.xml");

    Assert.IsTrue(studentList.Count() > num);
}
```

The stack trace points back to a line of code in my `CreateStudentList` method that works just fine if I insert it directly into the test itself (the method as a whole works well when I run it normally).

```
String xData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Report));
Report dataConverted = (Report) x.Deserialize(new StringReader(xData)); 
// the last line is where the stack trace ends
```

Anyone have a guess as to where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: 
Here's a link to some of the `StudentListGenerator` class, which contains the `CreateStudentList` method: https://gist.github.com/jekrch/eecdd1c8de8a11268be0

And here's the full stacktrace:

> at PFdata.Dashboard.Data.StudentListGenerator.CreateStudentList(String
>   filePath) in
>   C:\Users\CodeCamp\Desktop\StudentDataDashboard\StudentDataDashboard\Dashboard.Data\StudentListGenerator.cs:line
>   41 at DashboardTests.StudentDataCalcTests.firstTest(Int32 num) in
>   C:\Users\CodeCamp\Desktop\StudentDataDashboard\DashboardTests\StudentDataCalcTests.cs:line
>   22 Result Message:    System.NullReferenceException : Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the stacktrace on the original error was misleading. The real source of the NullReferenceException in the CreateStudentList method that I was testing was the following line:

```
Application.Current.Properties["reportMonth"] = reportMonth;
```

The problem was that the Application class was not being instantiated by the test. So the solution was to simply instantiate the application at the beginning of the test like so,

```
var app = new Application();
```

I got the idea to try this from a [comment by Ben Raupov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31003981/4830695) regarding a question about a similar issue. Many thanks to Unicorn2 for helping me factor out a number of other possibilities.

Comment: Np, I deleted my previous answer, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Thanks again for sticking it out with me. You're the best!

Comment: Programming is all about sticking it out sometimes hey? :P